# have antd modal height and width 100

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

i'm trying to figure out how to have antd modal open and have height of 100% and width of 100%, tried different ways but always getting scroll y and x, and if i put height of 100vh then using different mobile devices it still can scroll down for some reason, so my question is how to get this modal perfectly 100% height and width without any scrollings, here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/to-customize-the-width-of-modal-antd4154-forked-kfbzj?file=/index.css

Answer (score 1):

Please take reference from the below solution, setting below CSS worked for me:
https://codesandbox.io/s/to-customize-the-width-of-modal-antd4154-forked-r0e0k?file=/index.css

```
.ant-modal {
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 85px 43px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: there are still margins around the modal

Comment: your requirement is to have a height of 100% and a width of 100%, right?

Comment: yes, like it would be a page, without any margins

Comment: there is no margin in it, although .ant-modal-body class has some padding, you can simply remove it anytime, or use margin: 0px, in the parent class

Comment: there are margins from example i can see and also try to increase size of windows, width is not 100 %

Comment: Will `overflow: hidden;` of `.ant-modal`, the modal content may be cut off

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help https://codesandbox.io/s/to-customize-the-width-of-modal-antd4154-forked-mxx4j?file=/index.js

For more information:

- Change modal's width to "100vw"
- Change modal content to 100vw x 100vh with overflow auto